# Derailleur hanger bent

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear

How can I bent it back
Because its one of those the hanger is a part of the derailleur
If I want to get a new one its the whole derailleur replaced with it [image: pic of bent derailleur]

Comment: Large adjustable spanner. the quality of your derailleur, approx is ok. do not bend the derailleur, only the hanger.

Comment: A photo from the side might help - this appears to be a claw adapter which are readily available, and not a dedicated part of the rear derailleur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Savvy Cyclist is right, a hanger alignment tool is the best way to straighten the hanger. For some bikes, like yours, a hanger alignment tool won't work.

For bikes that have derailleurs that can't be removed from the hanger, or for inexpensive derailleurs you can bend it by hand and eyeball if it's straight.

The key to eyeball straightening is knowing what you are comparing to for straightness.

[image]

In your picture - you want the red line - the derailleur hangar - to be parallel to the green line - the drop out.

Grip the derailleur cage so that you can apply force such that the derailleur hanger will bend in the right place.
The red arrow indicates where force will need to be applied
[image]
In some cases I've used a large adjustable wrench to grab the hanger bolt (or hanger rivet in this case) and apply force on the hanger.

It takes some experimentation, but it can be done. Start by bending a little, checking, and repeat.

Comment: *In some cases I've used a large adjustable wrench to grab the hanger bolt (or hanger rivet in this case) and apply force on the hanger.*  I'd recommend that over grabbing the derailleur and pulling - if possible.  Simply grabbing and pulling could just bend the hanger the opposite way in a different location, most likely up by the frame, leaving a sharp bend outward near the frame and the existing bend inward.  That would make aligning the derailleur impossible.  Much better to remove the derailleur and use that large adjustable wrench on the unbent part and use that to straighten the hanger.

Comment: In this case (assuming the derailleur can't be removed from the hanger), I'd work that wrench onto the flat portion of the hanger between the derailleur and the frame and carefully straighten it that way.  And be prepared to buy a new one if I bodge it.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to do it.               Is it too bent to be straight?

Comment: @Mahmoudll it's fixable!

Comment: Ok Thank you 

Answer (score 3):

If the derailleur hanger is bent and it is not possible to separate it from the derailleur, it may be difficult to straighten it without causing further damage. If you are not confident in your ability to repair the hanger, it is recommended to take it to a bike shop for repair. The shop should be able to straighten the hanger or replace the entire derailleur if necessary.

If you are comfortable with attempting the repair yourself, you will need to use a hanger alignment tool or a flat surface such as a workbench to straighten the hanger. First, remove the wheel and derailleur from the bike. Then, place the hanger on the alignment tool or flat surface and gently apply pressure to the bent area until it is straight. Be sure to use caution and apply pressure slowly and evenly to avoid causing further damage to the hanger or derailleur. Once the hanger is straight, reattach the derailleur and wheel to the bike and test the shifting to ensure it is functioning properly.

Comment: Thank you I will try to do it by my self